How to use resource that is already "in use" in scene
I started looking at a demo project in Godot (an included demo project for different particle effects), and there were GPUParticles2D nodes that spawned particles randomly along the white pixels of a png-mask that I could identify as mask.png in the res:// folder, but when I looked at the nodes in the inspector, one node's process material's emission_point_texture referenced res://particles.tscn::ImageTexture_sshgl.
On another node that clearly uses the same mask.png resource, it has a different path res://particles.tres::ImageTexture_4v5mq instead. I believe this means that the texture is embedded as different objects in the scene, because when I made the GPUParticles2D-node into a separate scene, the path changed to that scene instead.
I wanted to use the demo to learn how to recreate this text-mask particle vfx, so I tried to create a GPU2DParticlesNode with a new ImageTexture for the emission points texture, and set the path to res://mask.png. This fails because of a "possible cyclic resource inclusion" error.
When I checked "edit dependencies" and "view owners" of mask.png, they showed up empty. But when I clicked "edit dependencies" it also warned that the resource was "in use". I don't know exactly how to interpret this.
How do I set the emission points texture to be the mask.png? I understand that the current setup doesn't allow this directly, but I can't see the resources anywhere, so how can I reference the mask.png if I create a new ImageTexture?

Did per chance the problem go away closing and opening the project again? I'm thinking the resource was loaded in memory by a resource that wasn't saved or was removed.

Oh I have to try that!

@Theraot Nope, still same issue. I think it might be some advanced configuration for embedding the png into the scene that makes it not importable by other means. But I am not sure.
